# AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm, data-science

Hello Im fairly new to all of these stuff trying to learn on my own but I keep getting stuck here and there, till now I figured it out somehow but this time the matplotlib dont want to work for me , can anyone help my with this ?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
us_babies = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Asuma\Downloads\Ex_Files_Intro_Data_Science\Exercise Files\us_baby_names.csv")
print(us_babies)

my_name = us_babies.loc[us_babies["Name"] =="Mehdi", :]
print(my_name)

my_chart = my_name.plot.barh(x="Year", y="Count")
print(my_chart)
```

and after this I'm keep getting this message instead of a plot > [image]

Comment: `print(my_chart)` ----> `plt.show()`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/eVJZ1xS
did not work out unless I put something wrong again

Comment: As @BigBen told, remove `print(my_chart)` and add `plt.show()` right at the end of your code. There should be no argument to `show`, just empty brackets!